# Converting non-standard date into SAS date in SAS

Tags: date, sas, substr

I have a date variable in the data. The value in the variable are not well formatted. I want to convert them into SAS date format like datetime9. .

date

Nov  2 2013 10:00AM
Oct  6 2012 11:00AM
Aug 26 2002 18:00PM
Mar 22 2012 07:00AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few functions to know about.

1. scan(str,n) -- this pulls the nth word from a string.
2. catt(str1,str2,str3) -- this concatenates strings.
3. input(str,informat) -- this converts a string to a number using the informat
4. dhms(d,h,m,s) -- Day Hour Minute Second.  A date, plus time parts equals a datetime.

Also `DDMONYYYY` is informat = `date9.`

`HH:MM <AM|PM>` is informat = `time.`

So...

```
data test;
format date $20.;
date = "Nov 2 2013 10:00AM"; output;
date = "Oct 6 2012 11:00AM"; output;
date = "Aug 26 2002 18:00PM"; output;
date = "Mar 22 2012 07:00AM"; output;
run;

data test;
set test;
format day date9. time time. date2 datetime.;
day = input(catt(scan(date,2),scan(date,1),scan(date,3)),date9.);
time = input(scan(date,4),time.);
date2 = dhms(day,hour(time),minute(time),second(time));
run;
```

Comment: what if the value become 2013-11-26 14:45:15?

Comment: You can still use the scan function.  It has an optional 3rd parameter that is the separator. MDY() works like DHMS() but with month, day, and year.  Check them both out in the SAS documentation.  Also, the `time.` informat should work with that time.

Comment: it shows Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
when I used time. .

Comment: Lu Yu, these informats can convert your example to SAS datetime values: ANYDTDTM, E8601DT, IS8601DT and YMDDTTM

Answer (score 1):

```
data any;
  attrib datevar format=date9.;
  infile cards;
  input datevar ANYDTDTM20.;
  datevar=datepart(datevar);
  cards;
Nov 2 2013 10:00AM 
Oct 6 2012 11:00AM 
Aug 26 2002 18:00PM
Mar 22 2012 07:00AM
;run;
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that comment, Lu Yu.

Comment: If the datetime value is "2013-11-06 11:05:12" you can still use the ANYDTDTM informat